# Sort Top 2 countries with max numbers group_by country from year 1919 to 1930

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Looking to sort Top 2 countries with  max number of fatalities group_by country from year 1919 to 1930

```
Input Data :

country  fatalities  month  year
 Italy          14      8  1919
  U.K.           1      8  1919
 Sudan           0      2  1920
 Italy          24      4  1957
 Italy          20      5  1930
  U.K.          36      6  1921
 Sudan          42      5  1927
```

OutPut:

```
    country  fatalities 
      Sudan         42 
      U.K.          37 


data1 = data.groupby(data['country'], sort=False)['fatalities'].sum().reset_index()
```

**It gives the Sum based on the GROUP BY but I need only top two based on year from 1919 to 1930**

Answer (score 3):

Create a boolean mask to filter your data first, using [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html). Then use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) and [`head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.head.html):

```
mask = df['year'].between(1919, 1930)

(df[mask].groupby('country', as_index=False)['fatalities'].sum()
 .sort_values('fatalities', ascending=False)
 .head(2))
```

[out]

```
  country  fatalities
1   Sudan          42
2    U.K.          37
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try applying [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to boolean index, [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) and [nlargest()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html)

```
df[df.year.between(1919,1930)].groupby('country')['fatalities'].sum().nlargest(2)

country
Sudan    42
U.K.     37
```